# Render Apex page via API and getting response?

Tags: apex, visualforce

We have API access via REST and need to grab the contents of a rendered page located at
https://xyz.visual.force.com/apex/page?id=x

Is there any API or way to render this remotely?

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @identigral we are trying to grab the html source of a page located at https://xyz.visual.force.com/apex/page?id=x

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So it turns out, you can access the page via an API bearer token.

Just pass it via `Authorization` header and you can get the page! I didn't see any documentation on this however.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to create a Rest class, you could create a very small class to render the page and return it to you as a string.

Something like:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/PageContent/*')
global with sharing class PageContentService {

  @HttpGet
  global static String getPageContent(){
    String pageId = RestContext.request.params.get('id');
    Blob pageContent;
    PageReference pageref = Page.YourPage;
    pageRef.getParameters().put('id',x);

    pageContent = pageref.getContentAsPDF);
    return pageContent.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: sometimes there are some differences when accessing the parameters of the get request - I think this is the right way, but I haven't tested.